# Handle 2 objects in map() function in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a tricky question, at least for me, today. First of all I want to present you the code example which I want to acomplish:

```
var numbers= [1,2,3,4]; 

var newNumbers = values.map((v1, v2) => {
  return v1+v2; 
}); 

console.log(newNumbers ); //[wanted output: 3, 7]
```

The idea behind that is that I can map over an array but not with one item like usualy, this time I want to do this with pairs. Also I want to handle this little problem incase I have an odd amount of numbers:

```
var numbers= [1,2,3,4,5]; 

var newNumbers = values.map((v1, v2) => {
  return v1*v2; //when v1 is 5 and v2 out of range, treat v2 as 0
}); 

console.log(newNumbers ); //[wanted output: 2, 12, 0]
```

Is it possible to handle this in JS or does anybody have an idea how I could map over an array in this special way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map` is only for when the input array and output array items are one-to-one. Since you're looking to go from 4 items to 2, you'll need a different method.

A plain `for` loop works.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 2) {
  output.push(numbers[i] + (numbers[i + 1] || 0));
}
console.log(output);
```

The `|| 0` at the end there will work for when the last number isn't paired with another.

Comment: wouldn't that be better if you use `??` instead of `||`

Comment: You could, it'd make the logic being implemented more precise, but less compatible

Answer (score 1):

This is not extremely practical but a possible way to solve it using [ES6 iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators):

```js
function sumPairs(arr) {
  const result = [];
  
  const iterator = arr.values(); //1
  
  for (const x of iterator) {    //2
    const [y = 0] = iterator;    //3 and 4
    result.push(x+y);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

1. [`Array#values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) gets an iterator over the values of an array.
2. [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) will go through the iterator. That is how it works by spec - even if you use `for (const x of arr)` internally the `for..of` will get the default iterator of `arr` which is the same as `.values()`.
3. Using [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) also works on iterators by spec. The name is actually a bit misleading - it *looks* like an array because of the `[` and `]` and you can use it on arrays like `const [a, b, c] = someArray`.

   However destructuring assignment using square brackets will always draw from an iterator. If it is already given an iterator, it is the same as calling `iterator.next().value`. In the case of `const [y] = iterator` it would draw a second value after `x`. So, each iteration of the loop advances through two of the items of the array.
4. The destructuring assignment allows using some syntax sugar - in this case [specifying default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_values). With `[y = 0]` the second item drawn from the array will have a default if it happens to be `undefined`. The `for..of` will stop once there are no more items the iterator can produce.

   - if the array had an even number of items, then getting a `y` will be the last item, so the next iteration the loop ends:
   - if the array has an odd number of items, then `x` will be the last item of the iterator and `y` will get a value from an already exhausted iterator and thus the last iteration will just use the default for `y`.

```js
function pairs(arr) {
  const iterator = arr.values();
  
  for (const x of iterator) {
    const [y = 0] = iterator;
    console.log(x, y);
  }
}

pairs([1, 2]);
console.log("-----");
pairs([1, 2, 3]);
```

See also: [Iteration protocols on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)

---

The above approach can be generalised with a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) that accepts any iterable and returns pairs of items until it is exhausted.

```
function* pairs(iterable) {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  for (const x of iterator) {
    const [y] = iterator;
    yield [x, y];
  }
}
```

The `sumPairs` function then just needs to consume those pairs by summing them and then adding them to an array:

```js
function* pairs(iterable) {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  for (const x of iterator) {
    const [y] = iterator;
    yield [x, y];
  }
}

function sumPairs(arr) {
  const result = [];
  
  for (const [x, y = 0] of pairs(arr)) {
    result.push(x+y);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

With a generator in place, the `sumPairs` can furrther be condensed to just an [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), since it accepts any iterable as a first parameter and a mapping function for a second parameter.

```
const sumPairs = arr =>
  Array.from(pairs(arr), ([x, y = 0]) => x+y);
```

```js
function* pairs(iterable) {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  for (const x of iterator) {
    const [y] = iterator;
    yield [x, y];
  }
}

const sumPairs = arr =>
  Array.from(pairs(arr), ([x, y = 0]) => x+y);

console.log(sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```